# ColumnTransformer : 1D data passed to a transformer that expects 2D data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

It is the first time I am using ColumnTransformer and I face an issue with the dimension of the array.

Here is my dataframe called 'concat_data' :

```
          Date  Hour  Observation
0  01/09/2015      0           10
1  01/09/2015      1            9
2  01/09/2015      2            8
3  01/09/2015      3           10
4  01/09/2015      4           12
```

I am trying to apply a standard scaler only on the Observation column with the following code :

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('num', StandardScaler(), ['Observation'])],
        remainder="passthrough")

preprocessor.fit(concat_data, concat_data['Observation'])
```

I get this error message :

> ValueError: 1D data passed to a transformer that expects 2D data. Try
>   to specify the column selection as a list of one item instead of a
>   scalar.

I could do it without ColumnTransformer but my objective is to understand how ColumnTransformer works. For instance, this code works :

```
StandardScaler().fit(concat_data[['Observation']])
```

Thanks all !

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. On my system the code you posted works fine for `ColumnTransformer`. The error suggests to use a list of single item. But in your code you are already doing it in `['Observation']`. So are you sure that you are using the same code? Try updating the scikit-learn version to latest.

Answer (score -1):

**Try**

`preprocessor.fit(concat_data, concat_data)`

**or**

`preprocessor.fit(concat_data, concat_data[['Observation']])`

Also, might be useful: [example of using the ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-column-transformer-mixed-types-py)

### About using df['A'] and df[['A']]

In one case You still have a `pd.DataFrame`  - using `df[['A']]`, in the other case it is squeezed to `pd.Series` - `df['A']`.

`pd.Series` is considered as 1D object, because it is allowed to have one column; `pd.DataFrame` is a 2D object, allowed to have multiple column and treated accordingly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1]],index=[0,1],columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])

type(df[['A']])
```

Out[27]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

```
type(df['A'])
```

Out[28]: pandas.core.series.Series

The output for both cases is also slightly different.

Comment: Although your explanation about the `DataFrame` shape is correct, but in your answer, you are changing the second parameter i.e. `y` to 2-d vs 1-d. `y` is an optional parameter, which is not needed by StandardScaler, so also not used by `ColumnTransformer` even if you send 2-d or 1-d in it. It wont be used and the problem is not related to that.

Comment: Could You please extend, what exactly You mean? The question is not about the StandardScaler, but rather about ColumnTransformer.

Comment: Yes. But when you say try `this` or `that`, you are changing the second input parameter which in `ColumnTransformer` is `y` and optional. So unless the internal object, (the `StandardScaler`) uses it, it will not be used. The issue OP having is for the first input, i.e. `X`. So your suggestions are not relevant to that

Answer (score -1):

You should use `preprocessor.fit(concat_data)` directly and it will work, the `ColumnTransformer` expect only one `DataFrame` not two. And it will automatically look for the Column `Observation`

Answer (score -4):

Artur Sokolovsky, I also tried the scikit-learn's example and it also didn't work

As Vivek Kumar suggested, the issue was due to an old version of scikit-learn. Updating to 0.20.02 solved it.